# Create a Calendar Event from an embedded submit form

Tags: date, variables, events, time, calendar

I am using [this](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/calendar-services/create-calendar-events-by-submitting-form) script as a basis for creating calendar events from a submit form:

I have got the script working but I also want to be able to schedule a start time and end time as well.

I have added a list box to allow the user to select the start and end time, but cannot combine the 2 variables to create a single datetime that can be used to create the event.

```
//
//Create the GUI form

function doGet() {
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Form and Calendar Events');

//Create a penel which holds all the form elelemnts
var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('panel');

//Create the form elelemnts
var eventDateLabel = app.createLabel('Event Date:');
var eventDate = app.createDateBox().setId('eventDate');
var eventStartTimeLabel = app.createLabel('Event Start Time:');
var listBox = app.createListBox().setName('eventStartTime').setWidth('80px');
listBox.addItem('08:00:00 UTC+8');
listBox.addItem('08:20:00 UTC+8');
listBox.addItem('08:40:00 UTC+8');
listBox.addItem('09:00:00 UTC+8');
var eventFinishTimeLabel = app.createLabel('Event Finish Time:');
var listBox1 =    app.createListBox().setName('eventFinishTime').setWidth('80px');
listBox1.addItem('08:20:00 UTC+8');
listBox1.addItem('08:40:00 UTC+8');
listBox1.addItem('09:00:00 UTC+8');
listBox1.addItem('09:20:00 UTC+8');
var eventTitleLabel = app.createLabel('Event title:');
var eventTitle = app.createTextBox().setName('eventTitle').setId('eventTitle');
var eventDeatilLabel = app.createLabel('Event Details:');
var eventDetail = app.createTextArea()
  .setSize('200', '100').setId('eventDetail').setName('eventDetail');
var btn = app.createButton('createEvents');

//Create handler which will execute 'createEvents(e)' on clicking the button
var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('createEvents');
handler.addCallbackElement(panel);
//Add this handler to the button
btn.addClickHandler(handler);

//Add all the elemnts to the panel 
panel.add(eventDateLabel)
.add(eventDate)
.add(eventTitleLabel)
.add(eventTitle)
.add(eventStartTimeLabel)
.add(listBox)
.add(eventFinishTimeLabel)
.add(listBox1)
.add(eventDeatilLabel)
.add(eventDetail)
.add(btn);
//Add this panel to the application
app.add(panel);
//return the application
return app;
}

function createEvents(e){

//Get the active application
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

try{
//get the entries;
var eventDate = e.parameter.eventDate;
var eventTitle = e.parameter.eventTitle;
var eventDetails = e.parameter.eventDetail;
var eventStartTime = e.paremeter.eventStartTime;
var eventFinishTime = e.paremeter.eventFinishTime;
var eventBegin = eventDate + eventStartTime;
var eventEnd = eventDate + eventFinishTime;


    //Get the calendar
 //var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('Calendar-Name')[0];//Change the calendar name
 //End time is calculated by adding an hour in the event start time 
 //var eventEndTime = new Date(eventDate.valueOf()+60*60*1000);
 //Create the events
 //cal.createEvent(eventTitle, eventStartTime,eventEndTime ,{description:eventDetails});





 // Creates an event for the moon landing and logs the ID.
var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('Test')[0].createEvent(eventTitle,
 new Date(eventBegin),
 new Date(eventEnd),
 {location: 'test'});
Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());






//Log the entries in a spreadsheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('15lMblqQvgJqhmI7KP5J-ROEsfiUyX-MfJLiqU9hQJRQ');//Change the spreadhseet key to yours
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 5).setValues([[new Date(), eventDate,eventTitle, eventDetails, 'Event created']]);

//Show the confirmation message
app.add(app.createLabel('Event created Successfully'));
//make the form panel invisible
app.getElementById('panel').setVisible(false);
return app;
}

//If an error occurs, show it on the panel
catch(e){
app.add(app.createLabel('Error occured: '+e));
return app;
  }
}
```

There's a lot of commented out bits from where I've been playing around with this, but hopefully you get the gist. Fairly new to this, so apologies if this isn't clear.